# Extracting source code by using script language

Tags: bash, scripts, source-code, curl

I am trying to extract source code of a website. I code like this on my script file:

`curl http://www.example.com`

And the output is:

`<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>Moved Permanently</h1></center> 
</body>
</html>`

Just this! I can't get whole code. But why?  Should I use another command(if there any)?

I want to get source code of website (I mean html) But I see just a few line...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What output did you expect instead? Please add this to your question.

Comment: 301 means you are redirected (please have a look at good old [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) ) and therefore not getting the destination source code but only the code of the redirection page

Comment: What should I do about it? Any tips?

Comment: please consider [accepting the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) if it resolved your question, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `-L` option to "follow redirects" as described [here](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-follow-redirects) and of course also on the [man curl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/curl.1.html)

```
curl -L http://www.example.com
```

Maybe it would even be enough to use

```
curl https://www.example.com
```

since it says [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) that the most common reason for a 301 response is a former migration of the page from `http` to `https`.